# Excel - MATCH AND INDEX

Tags: excel, excel-match

I am trying to get the Tax Rate from the Sheet 2 (Tax Rates table).

[image]

Based on the information of Country and Income from Sheet 1:

- If it is employed = 0 or -1, then taxrate = 0.
- Else, I will continue to find the tax rate.

Below is my code:

```
=IF(OR(G2=0,G2=-1),0,INDEX(INDEX(TaxRates!D:D,MATCH(A3,TaxRates!A:A,0)):INDEX(TaxRates!D:D,MATCH(A3,TaxRates!A:A,0)+COUNTIF(TaxRates!A:A,A3)-1),MATCH(J3,INDEX(TaxRates!B:B,MATCH(A3,TaxRates!A:A,0)):INDEX(TaxRates!B:B,MATCH(A3,TaxRates!A:A,0)+COUNTIF(TaxRates!A:A,A3)-1),1)))
```

[image]

I am not sure where this goes wrong.

**Can anyone assist me with the correct solution?**

Comment: @teylyn can help pls?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `sumifs` rather than index/match here. This assumes that the tax rates are unique, but that seems reasonable in your example.

> =SUMIFS(TaxRates!D:D,TaxRates!A:A,a2,TaxRates!B:B,"<="&J2,TaxRates!C:C,">"&J2)

Plus of course, your outer `if` function.